# Django-Oscar with AWS S3 save images correctly

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage, django-oscar

I'm using `django-oscar` with S3 storage from the `storages` `S3BotoStorage` library. My static files are stored in my s3 bucket at:

```
STATIC_URL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/<my_bucket_name>/static/"
```

These are successfully collected when I run `python manage.py collectstatic`, so I know I have my S3 permissions set correctly.

My `MEDIA_URL` is set to:

```
MEDIA_URL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/<my_bucket_name>/media/"
```

When I run `python manage.py oscar_import_catalogue_images`, the images are saved to my S3 bucket, howerver, they are placed in:

```
<bucket_name>/images/products/2016/02/<image_file>
```

Although they are saved here, they are not correctly rendered on my site.

The images are rendered as an empty `<div>`, with large whitespace surrounded by quotes.

How can I get the images to be correctly rendered, and have `sorl` properly generate thumbnails from the S3 images?

Based on my preliminary research, I would have to edit the [`utils.py Importer`](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/utils.py) class somehow to change the directory. But I'm not sure that would help with how they are rendered. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was using a version of Python Image Library [(PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), that did not support my image format. After I `pip uninstall`'ed `PIL`, I added the necessary support libraries, and then reinstalled `PIL`. This solved the issue.